# ORMLite DataType.SERIALIZABLE HashMap not working

Tags: java, ormlite

I'm receiving the following error at trying to store a HashMap.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORMLite can't store unknown class class java.util.HashMap for field
    'extra'. Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
```

The class to be stored:

```
public class SyncDTO implements Serializable {
    ...
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    private HashMap<String, String> extra;
    ...

    public HashMap<String, String> getExtra() {
        return extra;
    }

    public void setExtra(HashMap<String, String> extra) {
        this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

I also have it declared in a `ormlite_config.txt` as:

```
#################################
# --table-start--
...
# --field-start--
dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
fieldName=extra
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
```

I've seen other problems about it, but so far it looks like I'm doing what is expected to be done to store serializable fields, am I missing something?

Comment: On the surface, your code and config look good.  Have you tried running without the `ormlite_config.txt` field?  Maybe it is a out of date or has some other problem?

Comment: Couldn't wait any longer, I've implemented by serializing the map into a json and storing it as an String.